# как правильно построить триггер на удаление mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

мне нужно удалить строку по id из двух связанных таблиц

Создание таблиц:

```
create table pet_owner(
id_owner int not null auto_increment,
first_name varchar(50) not null,
second_name varchar(50),
last_name varchar(50) not null,
phone varchar(10) not null,
owner_password varchar(50) not null,
email varchar(50),
primary key (id_owner));

create table pet(
id_pet int not null auto_increment,
id_owner int not null,
animal_type varchar(20) not null,
breed varchar(50) not null,
pet_name varchar(20) not null,
age double not null,
sex BIT(1) not null,
primary key (id_pet),
foreign key (id_owner) references pet_owner(id_owner));
```

триггер:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER pet_owner_delete 
after delete 
on pet_owner
for each row
BEGIN 
    delete from pet_owner where pet_owner.id_owner=OLD.id_owner;
    delete from pet where pet.id_owner=OLD.id_owner;
END$$

delimiter ;
```

и его использование:

```
delete from pet_owner
where id_owner = 1;
```

Ошибка которую выводит

Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`happy_pet`.`pet`, CONSTRAINT `pet_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_owner`) REFERENCES `pet_owner` (`id_owner`))

Comment: Хм... Не удаляется потому что триггер удаления из pet_owner запускает удаление из pet, в котором есть внешний ключ на pet_owner... Получился какой-то замкнутый круг... Вот это лишнее `delete from pet_owner where pet_owner.id_owner=OLD.id_owner;`. Вообще есть смысл выкинуть триггер, и сделать FK как ON DELETE CASCADE https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html тогда будет каскадное удаление

Comment: Да каскадное удаление выглядит куда привлекательнее , но мне бы очень хотелось научится стоить триггеры, я попытался удалить строчку, обновил триггер и ошибка осталась та же

Comment: Во первых триггер на таблицу pet_owner не должен сам из нее ничего удалять. Во вторых вы сделали after триггер, а значит он срабатывает только после успешного удаления строки. А строка не может быть удалена, пока не сработает триггер ... Попробуйте использовать before триггер и удалять в нем только из таблицы pet.

Comment: да всё заработало спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER pet_owner_delete 
before delete 
on pet_owner
for each row
BEGIN 
    delete from pet where pet.id_owner=OLD.id_owner;
END$$

delimiter ;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]